# Is the toString() method in java.util.Date locale independent?

Tags: java, java.util.date

```
    try {
         SimpleDateFormat strTemp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyy", Locale.US);
          Date reasult = strTemp.parse(input);
         String   checkDate = reasult.toString().substring(8, 10) + reasult.toString().substring(4, 7) + reasult.toString().substring(26);
         if (!checkDate.toUpperCase().equals(input))
             return false;

         else
          return true;
       } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
     }
```

As the API tells me java.util.Date.toString() is like format "dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy", I just want to know if the content format of toString() will be change while the windows locale changed? Such as "Russian","English", suggest the input is same, the checkDate value is same? Thanks for you help.

Comment: As a general rule, you should not rely on toString() of any class, except for throwaway code, because it's liable to change from one version to another. In the case of Dates, I'd advise using a DateFormat to guarantee the output format.

Comment: Parsing toString() is also inelegant and inefficient. Better use a Calendar in this particular case.

Comment: @ignis Yes. Henry why are you doing this check? Don't you trust SimpleDateFormat to parse the date correctly? If you want to check its behaviour, better to write a test where you feed it values (some wrong, some right) and check it handles them as you wish.

Comment: It is cause by the TimeZone as nhahtdh said.The format"dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy" isn't adjust to each TimeZone and cause the substring collect error characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Date.toString()` is locale independent. The most significant change that you can ever observe is the timezone, which depends on the timezone settings of your computer. This is [by design](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29).

> Converts this Date object to a String of the form:
>
> ```
>    dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy
> ```
>
> where:
>
> - `dow` is the day of the week (`Sun`, `Mon`, `Tue`, `Wed`, `Thu`, `Fri`, `Sat`).
> - `mon` is the month (`Jan`, `Feb`, `Mar`, `Apr`, `May`, `Jun`, `Jul`, `Aug`, `Sep`, `Oct`, `Nov`, `Dec`).
> - `dd` is the day of the month (`01` through `31`), as two decimal digits.
> - `hh` is the hour of the day (`00` through `23`), as two decimal digits.
> - `mm` is the minute within the hour (`00` through `59`), as two decimal digits.
> - `ss` is the second within the minute (`00` through `61`, as two decimal digits.
> - `zzz` is the time zone (and may reflect daylight saving time). Standard time zone abbreviations include those recognized by the method parse. If time zone information is not available, then `zzz` is empty - that is, it consists of no characters at all.
> - `yyyy` is the year, as four decimal digits.

Comment: Do you mean when use Date.toString(), it will always output "dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy"? It is unrelated windows locale?

Comment: @Henry: The format and the day of week/name of month are the same regardless of locale.

Comment: Hmm.. the substring is just collect seperate part and concat to "ddMMMyy", is it safe under different windows locale and timezone? As my customer report me a error which I'm sure it is happened in these codes.

Comment: @Henry: You can take a look at the other answers or the source code on GrepCode - I don't see anything suggesting that it is dependent on locale (but it does depend on timezone). Regarding bugs, this might be interesting to you: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6483402

Answer (score 2):

It will not change as its locale independent. There used to be `toLocaleString()` but its now deprecated.

You can see the code -

```
public String toString() {

    // "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
    BaseCalendar.Date date = normalize();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(28);
    int index = date.getDayOfWeek();
    if (index == gcal.SUNDAY) {
        index = 8;
    }
    convertToAbbr(sb, wtb[index]).append(' ');                        // EEE
    convertToAbbr(sb, wtb[date.getMonth() - 1 + 2 + 7]).append(' ');  // MMM
    CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getDayOfMonth(), 2).append(' '); // dd

    CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getHours(), 2).append(':');   // HH
    CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getMinutes(), 2).append(':'); // mm
    CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getSeconds(), 2).append(' '); // ss
    TimeZone zi = date.getZone();
    if (zi != null) {
        sb.append(zi.getDisplayName(date.isDaylightTime(), zi.SHORT, Locale.US)); // zzz
    } else {
        sb.append("GMT");
    }
    sb.append(' ').append(date.getYear());  // yyyy
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Carefull with the time zone! Aside from that, no, it will not change according to the locale. Check the source code (that's always a good idea!) for the `java.util.Date.toString()` method:

```
 public String toString() {
    // "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
    BaseCalendar.Date date = normalize();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(28);
    int index = date.getDayOfWeek();
    if (index == gcal.SUNDAY) {
        index = 8;
    }
    convertToAbbr(sb, wtb[index]).append(' ');            
    ...
```

And that wtb is a private final static string:

```
private final static String wtb[] = {
    "am", "pm",
    "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday",
    "saturday", "sunday",
    "january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june",
    "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december",
    "gmt", "ut", "utc", "est", "edt", "cst", "cdt",
    "mst", "mdt", "pst", "pdt"
};
```

So, nope, it won't change, it'll always be English names.

UPDATE: as @nhahtdh pointed out, the Time Zone will change depending on where the computer regional config is set

Answer (score 0):

Normally `toString()` is responsible for convert to String. It is not matter what is your locale changes on local system.

```
    //Now my local date time (US & CANADA)
    Date dt1=new Date();    
    System.out.println("Date is ::"+dt1.toString());
```

It works with your locale automatically.This above code is also working fine.